# How to Preload 'Realm' DB into iOS swift3?

Tags: ios, swift3, realm

I am trying to implement Realm database in my app , I have realm database with some Preloaded data into it . I have searched through many stack overflow resources but didn't get any success.

So far now , I have done following steps :

1. Copy the Realm File into my app's bundle
2. Added following code in the app delegate :

   ```
   path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "data", ofType: "realm")
   var config = Realm.Configuration(fileURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath:      path!))
   config.readOnly = true

   // Open the Realm with the configuration
   let realm = try! Realm(configuration: config)
   ```

But this doesn't work , Please provide some solution to it .

Note : I don't want to migrate my database.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The piece of code below works perfectly for me to load a preloaded Realm instance during the first launch of my app:

```
let defaultPath = Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL?.path
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "default", ofType: "realm")
if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: defaultPath!), let bundledPath = path {
    do {
        try FileManager.default.copyItem(atPath: bundledPath, toPath: defaultPath!)
    } catch {
        print("Error copying pre-populated Realm \(error)")
    }
}
```

Comment: When i try to add new model named as 'Person' into it , it gets added . but when i opened it in realm browser it is showing only one model which was originally there i.e 'Medicine'. Do you have any idea about whats going  inside of realm ??

Comment: do you do `let realm = try! Realm()` after the if block? Also where did you put this code? It should be in the AppDelegate's `func application(didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)`

Comment: After deleting app when I reinstalled it  , it is not copying the default. Realm to the DB. I am not getting what's happening in it.

Comment: Did you try debugging the code? Is it going into the if statement? If yes, does the try fail?

Comment: yes actually I debugged the code , I found that path is getting nil . I didn't get why this path is nil. I have added the Realm file into project bundle.

Comment: Then it seems like your default.realm file is not part of your application bundle anymore. Are you sure you didn't delete it by accident or renamed it and didn't rename it in code?

Comment: let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Medicine", ofType: "realm")
This Medicine.realm is in copy bundle resources.

Comment: when I try to access that medicine.realm using above code , the path which i am getting in app delegate is nil.

Comment: Solved the problem by adding the Medicine.realm into copy bundle resources . Initially it wasn't in the bundle resources. Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 1):

Select your realm file in Xcode Project Navigator then go open file inspector pane and check Target Membership box for your current target. Your code will work already!